# Subgroup of particular order.

Tags: group-theory

Is the following true? I tried $D_3$ and $Q_8$ and it seems true: ($G$ is a group)
$$k\mid |G|, k<|G| \implies G_k = \left\{H\mid H\le G, |H|=k\right\}= \left\{\langle g\rangle\mid g\in G, |g|=k\right\}$$
For $Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$
$$Q_{8,1}=\{\langle1\rangle\}, Q_{8,2}=\{\langle-1\rangle\}, Q_{8,4}=\{\langle i\rangle,\langle j\rangle, \langle k\rangle\}$$
For $D_3=\langle a,b|a^3=1,b^2=1,b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$
$$D_{3,1}=\{\langle 1\rangle\}, D_{3,2}=\{\langle b\rangle, \langle ab\rangle, \langle a^2b\rangle\}, D_{3,3} = \{\langle b\rangle\}$$

Comment: If it were true, then every finite group would be cyclic. Note that a finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of order $|G|$ in the symmetric group on $|G|$ generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False, of course.

Consider $G = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$, the elementary abelian 2-group of rank 3. Then

- $\{\, H \mid H \le G,\ \lvert H \rvert = 4\,\} \neq \emptyset$, but
- $\{\, \langle g \rangle \mid g \in G,\ \lvert g \rvert = 4 \,\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: But this does not satisfy $k < |G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, it is because he added that hypothesis after I posted.

Comment: Ah sorry - there could still be more iterations of this process!

Comment: True. It is because I revised my answer after you commented. (I hope this process terminates here.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a finite group.Consider

$(A)$ $\{H\le G:\mid H\mid =k\}=\{\langle g\rangle \le G:\mid g\mid =k\}$ for every proper divisor of $G$

$(B)$ Every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

Then $(A)\Leftrightarrow (B)$.Now $Q_8$ and $D_p(p$ being prime$)$ have the property $(B)$ so, the result follow s. For a counterexample take a group not satisfying $(B)$, the minimum ordered group for this counterexample is $D_4$ or $\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_2$